# Copy range from multiple workbooks to new worksheets in a master workbook using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I have a bunch of files and I'm running a loop to do some calculations. This loop is already done, but I am saving the results to new files, according to the original one.

```
    file1.xlsx
    file2.xlsx
```

after running the code:

```
    results/file1_results.xlsx
    results/file2_results.xlsx
```

This is the loop through files:

```
    directory = os.getcwd()  
    
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        wb = load_workbook(filename)  
        ws = wb.active
        max_row = ws.max_row
        
        ws["CX1"] = "Humanas"
        for row in range(2, max_row + 1):
            ws["CX{}".format(row)] = round((
                                    ws['R{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['U{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['X{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AA{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AD{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AG{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AJ{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AM{}'.format(row)].value ) * (50/8))

        ws["CY1"] = "Exatas"
        for row in range(2, max_row + 1):
            ws["CY{}".format(row)] = round((
                                    ws['AP{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AS{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AV{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['AY{}'.format(row)].value ) * (50/4))

        ws["CZ1"] = "Linguagens"
        for row in range(2, max_row + 1):
            ws["CZ{}".format(row)] = round((
                                    ws['BB{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BE{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BH{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BK{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BN{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BQ{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BT{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BW{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['BZ{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CC{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CF{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CI{}'.format(row)].value ) * (50/12))

        ws["DA1"] = "Biológicas"
        for row in range(2, max_row + 1):
            ws["DA{}".format(row)] = round((
                                    ws['CL{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CO{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CR{}'.format(row)].value + 
                                    ws['CU{}'.format(row)].value ) * (50/4))

        wb.save('results/' + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_results.xlsx')
        wb.close

    else:
        continue
```

The data is a bunch of dummies (0 or 1)

I need to adjust the results to a single file.xlsx.
I need to get multiple worksheets(named as original files or close to this).
I don't want to merge into a single ws

I am trying to copy the range of all results.xlsx and place into the new file. But no success.
A good alternative could be skip the creation of all files and place results directly into the final one, but I can not figure how to do this.

**Edit 1** - Got success of joining all of results in specific worksheet, but now, I need to clean up all of them to get only the results.

```
dest_wb = Workbook()
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for root, dir, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for file in filenames:
        file_name = file.split('.')[0]
        file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
    
        # Create new sheet in destination Workbook
        dest_wb.create_sheet(file_name)
        dest_ws = dest_wb[file_name]

        source_wb = load_workbook(file_path)
        source_sheet = source_wb.active
        for row in source_sheet.rows:
            for cell in row:
                dest_ws[cell.coordinate] = cell.value


dest_wb.save("results/report.xlsx")
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: At the end of process, i want a single file, with different worksheets for each original file, only with the 4 resulting rows in each one.

Answer (score 1):

Did this to the results:

```
dados = pd.read_excel("results/report.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
df = pd.concat(dados[frame] for frame in dados.keys())

lista_colunas = [7, 10, 101, 102, 103, 104]
filtro = df.columns[lista_colunas]
final_df = df[filtro]

grouped_df = final_df.groupby(final_df.columns[1])
salas = grouped_df.groups.keys()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('results/resultado.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for sala in salas:
        splitdf = grouped_df.get_group(sala) 
        splitdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(sala)) 
writer.save()
```